# TypeError: Member "equal" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert)

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

Truffle v5.0.8 (core: 5.0.8)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.13.0
Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37

Assert.equal worked in Truffle 4.x.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;


import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Funding.sol";

uint public initialBalance = 10 ether;
Funding funding;

function () external payable {}

function beforeEach() public {
    funding = new Funding();
}

function testSettingAnOwnerDuringCreation() public {
    Assert.equal(funding.owner(), this, "Owner should be the same as deployer.");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply open file `Assert.sol` and find out?

Comment: I believe it's dynamically generated - or, at any rate it's not on disk. As far as I can tell this seems to have something to do with Visual Studio Code Solidity extension. It was working fine under a previous version of truffle. But if I roll back then another project I have won't compile.

Comment: Check under `/node_modules/truffle-contract`.

Comment: That folder doesn't exist. I'm on windows btw.

Comment: Well, what Truffle-related folders do you have under `node_modules` then?